# Spring Bean setting doesn't work, no such bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I am making a Spring Bean for practice.
It is very simple bean setting yet keep showing me an error,

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'bye2' available
```

Here is my `root-context.xml` file

```
<bean id="bye2" class="com.jun.test.Bye2">
    <property name="one" value="one" />
    <property name="two" value="two" />
</bean>
```

And this is Bean Class,

```
public class Bye2 {

private String one;
private String two;

public Bye2() {
}

public String getOne() {
    return one;
}

public void setOne(String one) {
    this.one = one;
}

public String getTwo() {
    return two;
}

public void setTwo(String two) {
    this.two = two;
}
```

And this is the main method that calls the bean.

```
public class ByeMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Configloc = "classpath:root-context.xml";
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Configloc);
        Bye2 bye2 = ctx.getBean("bye2", Bye2.class);
        bye2.setOne("one");
        bye2.setTwo("Two");
        System.out.println(bye2.getOne());
        System.out.println(bye2.getTwo());
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usage of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` is incorrect for your context. You should be using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. Check the doc of `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html

So please try the below :

`AbstractApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(Configloc);`

Comment: @KimHyungJune is your issue sorted?

Comment: How didn't I see the difference? It's sorted. Thanks!